# Intel xmm registers do not load and multiply correctly

Tags: gdb, load, intel, multiplication, sse

I have written the following assembly programme to test how xmm registers multiply data;

```
# file: xmm.a
.global _start:
_start:
movsd (%rip), %xmm4
movsd -8(%rip), %xmm7
mulsd %xmm4, %xmm7
jmp _start
```

and assembled with `as xmm.a -o xmm.o` and linked with `ld xmm.o -o xmm`
after that I `gdb`'ed the _start function with `gdb --args ./xmm`

then reached the following screen output:

the programme should read the 16 byte of code data directly into both `xmm4` and `xmm7` and multiply them howvever it seems that it is not doing so

My system is ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Windows Subsystem for Linux on a intel i7 core machine

```
(gdb) disassemble /r  _start

  Dump of assembler code for function _start:

       0x00401000 <+0>:     f2 0f 10 25 00 00 00 00 movsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm4
       0x00401008 <+8>:     f2 0f 10 3d f8 ff ff ff movsd  -0x8(%rip),%xmm7   <_start+8>

       0x00401010 <+16>:    f2 0f 59 fc     mulsd  %xmm4,%xmm7

    => 0x00401014 <+20>:    eb ea   jmp    0x401000 <_start>

    End of assembler dump.

(gdb) x/8i _start-8

      0x400ff8:    add      %al,(%rax)
      0x400ffa:    add      %al,(%rax)
      0x400ffc:    add      %al,(%rax)
      0x400ffe:    add      %al,(%rax)
      0x401000 <_start>:    movsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm4
      0x401008 <_start+8>:  movsd  -0x8(%rip),%xmm7
      0x401010 <_start+16>: mulsd  %xmm4,%xmm7
   => 0x401014 <_start+20>: jmp    0x401000 <_start>

(gdb) print $xmm4

    $3 = {v4_float = {2.38630424e-29, -nan(0x783d10), 0, 0}, v2_double = {-nan(0x83d100ff20000), 0}, v16_int8 = {
    0, 0, -14, 15, 16, 61, -8, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, v8_int16 = {0, 4082, 15632, -8, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      v4_int32 = {267517952, -508656, 0, 0}, v2_int64 = {-2184660617396224, 0}, uint128 = 18444559413092155392}

(gdb) print $xmm7

    $4 = {v4_float = {0.0351714566, -nan(0x7ffff8), 0, 0}, v2_double = {-nan(0xffff83d100ff2), 0}, v16_int8 = {
    -14, 15, 16, 61, -8, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, v8_int16 = {4082, 15632, -8, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      v4_int32 = {1024462834, -8, 0, 0}, v2_int64 = {-33335275534, 0}, uint128 = 18446744040374276082}

(gdb)
```

according to IEEE754 floating point standard, both the loaded data and multiplied data are not proper, I have no idea what I am missing here

Comment: You know you're loading bytes of machine code, right?  (And interpreting those bytes as IEEE binary64 bit-patterns).  The qword at `0(%rip)` is the 8 bytes following the end of the `movsd` instruction, which in this case is another `movsd` instruction with a RIP-relative addressing mode.  Normally you'd put `val1: .quad 1234.0` in `.section .rodata` and load from there with `movsd val1(%rip), %xmm4`.

Comment: According to your GDB output, both values are NaNs (look at the `v2_double` interpretation, or `print $xmm4.v2_double`) since they have all their exponent bits set.  That makes sense, the high bytes of the first double are the high bytes of the `rel32=-8` in the second `movsd` addressing mode, so that's all-ones.  We can see the byte values from the `v16_int8` interpretation.

Comment: Anyway, IDK what you expected to see or why you think this is wrong, since you didn't say what you expected.

Comment: Actually wait a minute, your XMM4 bytes don't match XMM7, even though the load addresses are the same (`_start+8`), and don't match the machine code hex dump.  (And the multiply doesn't change the bytes in XMM7 because it's NaN).  Your XMM4 is left-shifted by 2 bytes (but still truncated to the low qword).  I tried it on my own Linux system and XMM4 and XMM4 have identical values (before and after the mulsd).  But only after I got it to assemble by removing the `:` from `.global start:` to fix the syntax error.  So this isn't a [mcve] for that reason as well as not saying what you expected.

Comment: Your code *is* loading (twice) the 8 bytes of the second `movsd`, `f2 0f 10 3d f8 ff ff ff`.  The first byte of that is at `_start+8`, the last is at `_start+15`.  Both `movsd` loads have the same address.  (Your GDB output doesn't match for XMM4 which is weird; are you sure you tested with this version of the code?)  Anyway, `p /x $xmm4.v16_int8` is a good way to match up the bytes in XMM4 with the machine code hexdump.

Comment: I find it odd that your GDB disassembly doesn't include the `<_start+8>` address calculation for the first instruction.  It does for me.  Did you hand-edit this from a different version, or is my newer GDB (13.2) just different from yours?  I also can't explain why the low 2 bytes of your XMM4 are `0` and the rest of the data is shifted, like you did `psllq $16, %xmm4` after this movsd load.  Is that what you're talking about with the load "not working"?  And why are you multiplying at all with an FP multiply?

Comment: My gdb version is: v9.2

Comment: Those bit-patterns both represent NaN, so `mulsd` actually *doesn't* change XMM7, which is why it still matches the machine-code bytes.  I tried it myself on my own system after fixing the syntax error in the `.global` line.  (Also an Intel i7 (Skylake), in case it matters which NaN payload goes into the result.)  (Look at `.v2_double` to see GDB showing it as NaN, or `.v16_int8` and notice the high 12 bits are all set.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: GDB has historically sometimes had bugs that make it show wrong register values.  Or if this is WSL1, perhaps something's weird with its ptrace struct layout?  Perhaps `movsd %xmm4, (%rsp)` and use GDB's `x` to examine that stack space to see if it matches `xmm7` and the machine code, or if somehow XMM4 *did* get a bad value.  (And/or `pop %rax` or `mov (%rsp), %rax` to check that the integer value matches `%xmm4.v2_int64`, if we trust GDB to print integer register values.)

Comment: Anyway, you do realize that XMM7's value is what we'd expect, matching the machine-code bytes, right?  x86 is little-endian.  Is the only "problem" here the XMM4 value?  You still haven't edited your question to clarify what you expected to see, or what kind of multiply you wanted to do.